# How to disconnect civi contact record from Drupal user

Tags: drupal, contacts

I created a contact record for some testing using the site admin email address which is associated to the corresponding Drupal user account (user 1).

However it's now causing some problems with certain emails that go out, so I want to delete the contact record but I get an error message that I can't delete myself.

Can I / how do I break the connection between the two so I can safely delete the contact record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the civicrm_uf_match table in your Civicrm database.  Each Drupal user is connected to its corresponding Civi contact record there.

- The uf_id column is the Drupal user ID.
- The uf_name column is the email address associated with the Drupal user and Civi contact record.
- The contact_id column is the Civi contact record ID.

I don't know the ramifications of deleting the row which contains Drupal user 1, but you could certainly create a new Civi contact record (not yourself), and put that new contact ID in the row with uf_id 1 (replacing whatever value is in the contact_id column currently).  Once that is done, you could delete your test contact record safely.

Our Drupal user 1 is associated with a contact record named [myorg] Tech and the email address is tech@[myorg].org.  Thus our default address for mailings come from that address with no problems.

Hope that helps!