# Why do some contacts share the same Drupal user?

Tags: drupal, contacts

I've got a bit of a baffling issue and I'm not sure where to begin looking for fixes.

I have begun to notice several instances where I have several contacts that share a single Drupal user account. These are contacts who are clearly not the same person and have no business sharing a single Drupal account.

Edited to add:

- I'm using CiviCRM 4.6.8 and Drupal 7
- None of the contacts share the same email address
- Contacts are not synced via rules
- We have recently opened registrations for 2 very large events. The merge rule we're using is supposed to sync contacts on name and email address
- There is a profile used for site registrations. We collect name, email address, phone number, address, etc.

Any idea what might cause this to happen?

Comment: are you saying that eg cid 12 and cid 15 are both linked to uid 5?

Comment: Yes, that exactly. There are several instances of of several CIDs sharing a single UID.

Comment: Can you share a little more about your Drupal setup?  Do you have any modules enabled that sync users to contacts (via a rule or otherwise)?  Do you have a profile enabled that is used for Drupal registration?  Do you use the Webform integration module at all for sign ups of any kind?

Comment: Also, what version of Civi are you using?

Comment: Another thought too, have you recently used Synchronize Users to Contacts (under Administer > Users and Permissions)?

Comment: Any shared email addresses? (As email addresses appear in civicrm_uf_match.) Do you have logging enabled, as that might help show what funny business is happening in that table.

Comment: yep i was going to ask if eg cid 12 and cid 15 have the same email or not. i don't think i have ever seen multiple contacts to a user, other than if you are using a multisite set up ie multiple drupals wired to a single civi - which i presume this is not

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what is causing the contacts to share Drupal accounts, but to detach contacts from Drupal user accounts, you will need access to the civicrm_uf_match table in your CiviCRM database.

See the question [How to disconnect civi contact record from Drupal user?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3878/how-to-disconnect-civi-contact-record-from-drupal-user) and the answer I posted there on how to detach contacts.

Comment: Just wanna say that I'm extremely grateful for the API explorer right now.

Comment: Curiosity here, how are you using the API explorer to fix it?

Comment: I'm using the API explorer using entity "UFMatch" and action "Get" to find an afflicted contact by ID. Make note of the UFMatchID, then use a "Delete" action to delete that row by corresponding ID. Seems to work.

Comment: Brilliant!  Great solution.