# Is there a way to disconnect CiviCRM contacts and Drupal Users via the UI?

Tags: user-account

I have a connection between a Drupal User and a CiviCRM contact that I would like to remove. I found [this Q&A](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3878/how-to-disconnect-civi-contact-record-from-drupal-user) which describes how to do that on the database level.

I was however wondering if there is any way to do that via the UI. Any hints? (Using CiviCRM 4.6.9 and latest Drupal.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this via the UI. I am not sure what to suggest if you don't have easy access to the db.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a top-of-the-head thought and I am not sure I've thought through all the ramifications, but could you:

1. Create a new contact (blank, essentially, or with the same name)
2. Run a search that pulls both of these, and select to merge them
3. Flip the contacts so the old contact is considered the duplicate contact
4. Check the boxes to transfer all the info **except the Drupal user** to the new contact in the process of merging?

Test first, obviously!

Comment: Laryn, you beat me to the punch! I was just going to suggest something along those lines.

Comment: Nice idea Laryn, will try it out and let you guys know :)

Comment: Aaah to bad - the Drupal User ID will stay the same (there is no dedicated checkbox for it. I think the only way is to delete the Drupal User, then remove the Email in CiviCRM amd then re-create the Drupal User... will let you know how it goes.